# $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{Q}}=\emptyset$ in $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To prove that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$: I say that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\subset\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}.$

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, any open neighborhood of $x$ is of the forme $]x-r,x+r[$ and as there is a rational number between two real numbers  we have that $]x-r,x+r[\cap \mathbb{Q}\neq\emptyset $ so $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$.

To prove that $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{Q}}=\emptyset$ we have if $x\in \overset{\circ}{\mathbb{Q}}$ then there exists an open $x\in \Omega=]x-r,x+r[\subset \mathbb{Q}$ but this is impossible because there is element from $C_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{Q}$.

Is it correct?

Please how to prove that between two real numbers there is at least of from $C_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{Q} $?

thank you.

Comment: saying that any real can be approached by a sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ is exactly the same as $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} = \mathbb{R}$. Hence I think it may be good to include what your definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ and in particular $\mathbb{R}$ is. However what is $C_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: So how we can explain that $]x-r,x+r[\cap \mathbb{Q}\neq \emptyset$? @M.U.

Comment: "Between any two reals there exists a rational number". This follows from the archimedean principle (and well-ordering principle of $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: this is the proof??: http://www.math.usu.edu/~rheal/math4200/class_material/irrationals%20between.pdf what about the rest of the proof ?

Comment: @M.U. please...

Comment: that looks right.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider for example

$$ y =
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{|x-r|}{\pi}      & \quad \text{if } mcd(|x-r|,\pi)=1\\
    \frac{|x-r|}{2}  & \quad \text{otherwise }\\
  \end{cases}
$$

Then $y$ is irrational and $|x-y|<r$